# Are continued frequent visits to the UK required to remain a Registered Traveller?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

The UK's [Registered Traveller](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/eligibility) program requires frequent visits to qualify for an initial application. Once qualified, are continued frequent visits to the UK required to retain Registered Traveller status?

Answer (score 1):

Registered Traveller status is valid for [12 months from the day you submit your application](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/how-to-apply):

> The immigration officer will check that you meet the criteria and tell
>   you if you can become a member. Your 12 month membership will start on
>   the day you submitted your application.

After that, you need to [renew your application on a per-year basis](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/renew-or-update-your-membership) by paying additional fees. At this stage, I assume you need to prove / meet the same criteria as for normal applications which is "at least 4 visits to the UK in the past 24 months".

Comment: That's the question: is that *assumption* correct?